# Laravel Eloquent order by length of children then paginate

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection, laravel-relations

I have a Model named Topic. My topics have many views and many comments. Is there in any way I can combine the length of the views and comments and then sort the topics based on the total length of its views and comments? I also figured out that I also cannot use SortBy and then paginate the collection. I'm kinda stuck, thanks for any help!

Comment: Post your code related to Topic model and relations, please.

Comment: Show code what are you trying, whats current results, desired results. Abstract explanation doesnt work on StackOverflow

Comment: When you say "length" are you referring to the count? Like the total of comments or views?

Answer (score 1):

First step  get topic's and use each collect sort total length and step tow   make custom pagination .
For more guidence please send model and controller code